# WAMP Server accessible by all pc's in the local area but one

Tags: networking, wamp

I have installed wamp server in a local area network.

All the PCs are able to access the Apache default page when type http://server_pc_ipaddress,
but one pc can't access it. Unfortunately it's my boss laptop :D.

It is always connected to the network and having the same class of ip, subnet and the default gateway etc. I can ping successfully this laptop and vice versa. What could be the problem preventing this computer from accessing the server?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is the request timing out or are you getting a Not Found (404) error? If it is the first one, try typing the ip address of the machine, you may have some name lookup issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the firewall off on both devices for a moment and see if it works, if it does its being blocked and you need to allow whatever ports it is blocking.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. ill try turn off the firewall and see.